# MySQL Creating trigger on view - Error 1347

Tags: mysql, view, triggers

I'm supposed to write a trigger that checks `BEFORE INSERT` whether the record already exists, and then take some actions. I'm stuck with this error returned on issuing an `INSERT` statement against `Koncerty` view:

> Error Code: 1347. 'BazyLista3.Koncerty' is not BASE TABLE

Here's the code for **view** `Koncerty`:

```
CREATE VIEW Koncerty (`nazwa_klubu`, `adres_klubu`, `nazwa_zespolu`,
`ilosc_czlonkow_zespolu`, `data_wystepu`) AS  
( SELECT `nazwa_klubu`, `kb`.`adres`, `nazwa_zespolu`, `zs`.`ilosc_czlonkow`,
`data_wystepu` FROM `Koncert` AS kc
INNER JOIN `Klub` AS kb ON `kc`.`nazwa_klubu` = `kb`.`nazwa`
INNER JOIN `Zespol` AS zs ON `kc`.`nazwa_zespolu` = `zs`.`nazwa` );
```

And my **trigger**, where I have this error:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `before_koncerty_insert`
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `before_koncerty_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `Koncerty`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;

SELECT COUNT(*) INTO i FROM `Koncerty` WHERE 
`nazwa_klubu` = NEW.`nazwa_klubu` AND
`adres_klubu` = NEW.`adres_klubu` AND
`nazwa_zespolu` = NEW.`nazwa_zespolu` AND
`ilosc_czlonkow_zespolu` = NEW.`ilosc_czlonkow_zespolu` AND
`data_wystepu` = NEW.`data_wystepu`;



IF i > 0 THEN
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '58005'
SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Blad! Taka krotka juz istnieje';
END IF;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

**Tables**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Klub`
(
    `nazwa` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    `adres` varchar(70) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`nazwa`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Zespol`
(
    `nazwa` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    `ilosc_czlonkow` int(3) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`nazwa`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Koncert`
(
    `nazwa_klubu` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    `nazwa_zespolu` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    `data_wystepu` datetime NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (`nazwa_klubu`) REFERENCES `Klub`(`nazwa`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`nazwa_zespolu`) REFERENCES `Zespol`(`nazwa`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

How do I get around this issue?

Comment: I don't think MySQL supports triggers on views.

Comment: I'm saying you cannot create a trigger on a view. And preventing duplicates is better done using a primary or unique constraint on the base table

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MySQL does not support triggers on views.

The way to do this task is to make `Koncerty` a **table** without keys, in order to then operate on it with trigger actions. It all worked out just as I wanted.

Also, making `UNIQUE CONSTRAINTS` on records in tables does the job for the unique record, because it pops up an error when trying to add anything alike.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL does not support triggers on views, from [MySQL reference manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-trigger.html):

> You cannot associate a trigger with a `TEMPORARY` table or a view.

Comment: The accepted answer is correct, I just thought adding a reference would be nice.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. You can suggest an edit to my answer and include it, to keep it tight :-)

Answer (score -2):

The error might come if the view has used the database name in it. For example if a view has used a table as `<dbname>.<tablename>`:

```
create or replace view dealer_current_stage as
    select 
        dsc.dealer_id,
        dsc.new_stage current_stage,
        dsc.change_date last_stage_change_date
    from
        dealer_current_stage_pre dcsp
            left join
        risk.dealer_stage_changes dsc ON dsc.change_date = dcsp.max_stage_change_date
            and dsc.dealer_id = dcsp.dealer_id
    group by dsc.dealer_id;
```

Here, `risk` is a different database and its table is being used. So better do not use the separate database and table, if you have to use it then consider the privileges, etc.